# Applying CSS to dynamically named elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome-extension

I wrote a theme for Google+. It injects CSS/Javascript to replace some colors, background images, etc. They recently seem to have renamed a lot (most) of their classes and ID's. If I were to rewrite the code, is there a way to assign CSS (through javascript, presumably, like jquery's .css() function) to page elements with dynamic names?

EDIT: If so, how?

Code: https://github.com/bichiliad/G-Theme

Example: I used this to replace the logo:

> $(".a-U-Pg-T img:first").attr('src', logoURL);

However, with the new update, the div enclosing the logo is now ".a-fa-bh-T".

Comment: dynamically named elements? can you provide any examples?

Comment: Without putting some of your code its quite inconvenient and hard to suggest solutions

Comment: @Joseph, there's an example above.

Comment: since that's rather arbitrary  as to what they call it, there's really no way to do this :P you could make it less likely to break by using things like $("img[class]:contains('logo')"). other than that... you'll just have to wait for the beta to be official and the names somewhat standardized.

Comment: @XGreen, my source code is on Github. The link is above.

Comment: @Joseph, I'm afraid you're right. *gulp*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use jQuery `find()` and regex patterns to try to find the elements themselves based on their hierarchy, but if the hierarchy changes then that won't work either. And yes, you could use jQuery's `css()` to apply those styles.